# Rails production isn't updating static assets on server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running my code in a production environment locally before I actually do anything with it.  I noticed a bug in my javascript while I was in production, fixed it, and went back.  The bug persisted.  I tried it in dev, however, and the bug was fixed perfectly fine!  I've restarted the server, restarted my computer, and tried the solution listed in another SO question to touch /tmp/restart.txt, but nothing seems to get Rails to reload the assets.

I can tell that its not a browser issue, because after fixing the bug, I loaded the webpage in a browser that hadn't seen the production environment before and it exhibited the same behavior.

Here are my production configurations:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true 
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false.
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

How do I get rails to reload the static assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To regenerate the assets you run this command

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I would recommend having this set to false in production.rb, so apache/nginx will serve the assets.

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I'm running on windows and for some reason the assets aren't served at all when that command is set to false.  I'm eventually planning to move it over to linux, however, so I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
rake assets:clean
```

The assets were probably precompiled at one point, and now the server will always use those precompiled assets if they exist. You can also manually delete the /app-root/public/assets folder for the same effect.